# Reshape Pandas DataFrame with TimeSeries in rows instead of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I have a DataFrame *df* that contains price data (Open, Close, High, Low) for every day in the time from January 2010 to December 2021:

| Name | ISIN | Data | 02.01.2010 | 05.01.2010 | 06.01.2010 | ... | 31.12.2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | US9835635986 | Price Open | 12.45 | 13.45 | 12.48 | ... | 54.12 |
| Apple | US9835635986 | Price Close | 12.58 | 15.35 | 12.38 | ... | 54.43 |
| Apple | US9835635986 | Price High | 12.78 | 15.85 | 12.83 | ... | 54.91 |
| Apple | US9835635986 | Price Low | 12.18 | 13.35 | 12.21 | ... | 53.98 |
| Microsoft | US1223928384 | Price Open | 12.45 | 13.45 | 12.48 | ... | 43.56 |
| ... | .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am trying to reshape the table into the format below:

| Date | Name | ISIN | Price Open | Price Close | Price High | Price Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2010 | Apple | US9835635986 | 12.45 | 12.58 | 12.78 | 12.18 |
| 05.01.2010 | Apple | US9835635986 | 13.45 | 15.35 | 15.85 | 13.35 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 02.01.2010 | Microsoft | US1223928384 | 12.45 | 13.67 | 13.74 | 12.35 |

Simply transposing the DateFrame did not work. I also tried pivot which gave the error message that the operands ould not be broadcasted to different shapes.

```
dates = ['NAME','ISIN']
dates.append(df.columns.tolist()[3:]) # appends all columns names starting with 02.01.2010
df.pivot(index = dates, columns = 'Data', Values = 'Data')
```

How can I get this DataFrame in the desired format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) before pivoting with convert datetimes, last sorting `MultiIndex`:

```
df = (df.melt(['Name','ISIN','Data'], var_name='Date')
        .assign(Date = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y'))
        .pivot(index = ['Date','Name','ISIN'], columns = 'Data', values = 'value')
        .sort_index(level=[1,2,0])
        .reset_index()
        )
print (df)
Data       Date       Name          ISIN  Price Close  Price High  Price Low  \
0    2010-01-02      Apple  US9835635986        12.58       12.78      12.18   
1    2010-01-05      Apple  US9835635986        15.35       15.85      13.35   
2    2010-01-06      Apple  US9835635986        12.38       12.83      12.21   
3    2021-12-31      Apple  US9835635986        54.43       54.91      53.98   
4    2010-01-02  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
5    2010-01-05  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
6    2010-01-06  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
7    2021-12-31  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   

Data  Price Open  
0          12.45  
1          13.45  
2          12.48  
3          54.12  
4          12.45  
5          13.45  
6          12.48  
7          43.56
```

Another idea is first convert columns names for datetimes and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
L = df.columns.tolist()
df = (df.set_axis(L[:3] + pd.to_datetime(L[3:], format='%d.%m.%Y').tolist(), axis=1)
         .rename_axis('Date', axis=1)
         .set_index(L[:3])
         .stack()
         .unstack(2)
         .reorder_levels([2,0,1])
         .reset_index())
print (df)
Data       Date       Name          ISIN  Price Close  Price High  Price Low  \
0    2010-01-02      Apple  US9835635986        12.58       12.78      12.18   
1    2010-01-05      Apple  US9835635986        15.35       15.85      13.35   
2    2010-01-06      Apple  US9835635986        12.38       12.83      12.21   
3    2021-12-31      Apple  US9835635986        54.43       54.91      53.98   
4    2010-01-02  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
5    2010-01-05  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
6    2010-01-06  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   
7    2021-12-31  Microsoft  US1223928384          NaN         NaN        NaN   

Data  Price Open  
0          12.45  
1          13.45  
2          12.48  
3          54.12  
4          12.45  
5          13.45  
6          12.48  
7          43.56
```